# Are all elements in a power set unique?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If I have a finite set $X$ , then $P(X)$ is the set of all subsets. I was wondering if there is a case in which two subsets or more in the power set of $X$ are equal (same element grouping)?

Comment: Sets by definition have unique elements... powersets are no different.

Comment: It is more likely that you get responses if you provide some context and share your own thoughts on the subject. Regarding your question, if two sets are the same, "they" are a single element of $P(X)$.